# OpenNLP - Tokenize an Array of Strings

Tags: java, apache, nlp, opennlp

I am trying to tokenize a text file using the OpenNLP tokenizer.
What I do, I read in a .txt file and store it in a list, want to iterate over every line, tokenize the line and write the tokenized line to a new file.

In the line:

```
tokens[i] = tokenizer.tokenize(output[i]);
```

I get:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String
```

This is my code:

```
public class Tokenizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-token-max.bin");

    try {


      TokenizerModel model = new TokenizerModel(modelIn);
      Tokenizer tokenizer = new TokenizerME(model);

      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("ParsedRawText1.txt"),',', '"', 1);
      String csv = "ParsedRawText2.txt";
      CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv),CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

      //Read all rows at once
      List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();

      for(String[] output : allRows) {
             //get current row
             String[] tokens=new String[output.length];
             for(int i=0;i<output.length;i++){

                 tokens[i] = tokenizer.tokenize(output[i]);
                 System.out.println(tokens[i]);
             }

             //write line
             writer.writeNext(tokens);
         }
         writer.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      if (modelIn != null) {
        try {
          modelIn.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

Does anyone has any idea how to complete this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As compiler says, you try to assign array of Strings (result of `tokenize()`) to String (`tokens[i]` is a String). So you should declare and use `tokens` inside the inner loop and write tokens[] there, too:

```
    for (String[] output : allRows) {
        // get current row
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            String[] tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(output[i]);
            System.out.println(tokens);

            // write line
            writer.writeNext(tokens);
        }
    }
    writer.close();
```

Btw, are you sure that your source file is a csv? If it is actually a plain text file, then you split text by commas and gives such chunks to Opennlp, and it can perform worse, because its model was trained over normal sentences, not split like yours.

Comment: Hey Nikita, I understand what you said me, but can not fix it. Can you write me how you thought it must be? Thank you!

Comment: I've added code example. Is it what you tried to do?